# Did the ancient Hebrew modal music precede the ancient Greek modes?

Tags: theory

I am curious to find out if the ancient Hebrew modal music preceded the ancient Greek modes and also if they have any connection or influence to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say, because we don't know anything at all about ancient Hebrew modes.  There are no ancient Hebrew treatises that explain their scales, only modern attempts at reconstructing them based on gematria (Hebrew numerology).

Comment: So you're saying there's a bunch of PhD thesis topics waiting out there :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft- I wouldn't care to guess what might yet turn up.  I'm no expert, but what I've seen in the way of attempted reconstructions so far seem to be based on pretty flimsy evidence.